# Lazy loading with tab router navigation

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-material2

There seems to be a problem when using router navigation with lazy loaded modules. This works fine if I remove lazy loading. But here is my setup according to lazy loading modules:

In my app.template I have the main router-outlet defined.

I have the following root app router

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'user/:id', loadChildren: './user/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'
  }
]
```

When profile module is loaded into the main router-outlet it will display a page with two routing tabs and inside profile.module I have the following child routes defined

```
const ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: ProfileComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'subPath1', loadChildren: '../subModule1/subModule1.module#SubModule1Module' },
            { path: 'subPath2', loadChildren: '../subModule2/subModule2.module#SubModule2Module' },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES),
     ....
    ]
}
```

Inside profile.template I have routing tab defined like this

```
<nav md-tab-nav-bar>
          <a class="tab-label" md-tab-link [routerLink]="'subPath1'" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
            Sub path 1
          </a>
          <a class="tab-label" md-tab-link [routerLink]="'subPath2'" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
            Sub path 2
          </a>
        </nav>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When I route e.g. to /user/:id/subPath2 I would expect subModule2 to be loaded into the router-outlet of the md-tab-nav-bar but instead it is being loaded into the main application router-outlet. This closes the profile.component and  displays only submodule2 instead of displaying it inside the tab.

Any idea why this is not working with lazy loading modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Angular2 [RouterModule](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterModule-class.html)

> ***forChild*** creates a module that contains all the directives and the given routes, **but does not include the router service**.
>
> ***forRoot*** creates a module that contains all the directives, the given routes, **and the router service itself**.

I think you most use forRoot, because forChild get only child

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
```

Comment: Thanks, yes this seems to be the problem but I need forChild because I am lazy loading the module. When I removed the lazy loading it worked fine. Do you know how to make this work for lazy loading modules?

Comment: I didn't work with lazy but i think you need add component to children  `{ path: 'subPath1', component: ***SomeComponent*** , loadChildren: '../subModule1/subModule1.module#SubModule1Module' }`

Comment: Thanks alot, you were right adding the component did the trick. I will mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: I'm glad that you helped )

Comment: Same issue but didn't get it working. Actually I didn;t get what needs to be ***SomeComponent***

Comment: without SomeComponent. Only `path` and  `loadChildren`